# How to make sense of Bayesian updating when an event is necessary

Tags: bayesian

In thinking about Bayesian updating the following situation occurred to me, suppose you have a die and hypothesize that it's fair since you've gathered no evidence about this die.  If you toss it and obtain a 1, then in some sense you've gained incremental--if weak--evidence that the die is biased towards 1.  On the other hand, some outcome must occur.  So in some sense, obtaining any event's outcome should have produced no evidence at all for bias.

How would a Bayesian explain these competing intuitions about the scenario?

Answer (score 2):

First of all, this has nothing to do with Bayesian approach. In frequentist approach if you observed only a single value, then estimating the expected value from it would also yield a biased result. The same with Bayesian approach. The *key point* in here is estimating the uncertainty of such estimate, e.g. confidence intervals in frequentist setting, or highest density intervals in Bayesian setting. In each case you would learn that based on a single data point, the point estimate you got is very uncertain and in most cases the interval estimates would (should!) tell you that given your data, the the true expected value "can be literally anything" with high probability. There is no competing intuitions in here, statistics enable you to find point estimate, but they also help you with assessing how trustworthy is your estimate, and given only a single data point, they will not be very trustworthy.